# Spring Security Authentication Manager - break/exit after first provider

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In applicationContext-security.xml, I had added these two custom authentication providers to the authentication manager.

```
<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider1"/>
<authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider2"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

If I want to exit on the first provider after a certain condition (eg. INVALID_PASSWORD) and do not want to go to the next provider, what exception needs to be thrown?

I know this is not Spring's intended behavior which doesn't make sense, but is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it. By throwing an AccountStatusException, it will break the polling of remainder authentication providers.

Comment: +1. I guess this is the way designers intended. See for example https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-546

Answer (score 0):

Do it programmatically.

Inject provider2 into 1. Remove provider2 from the secruity-config.

Comment: That's one of the way to do. But if I have more than one authentication providers then I will have to inject all into the first provider, which is quite troublesome.

Comment: @WiltsC what behaviour to expereince at th emoment when an invlaid password is entered ?